# Allow editors to create pages (singles)

Tags: singles, editor

Seems like a very obvious (and missing) feature, but maybe I'm missing something. If we have a generic "page" template how could an editor (as in someone not confident with using settings) just create a new single page?

E.g they may have singles for about, history, faq's etc but then want to add a new "page" for a one-off thing. Right now the developer has to create a new single in settings for them which is really clunky.

Answer (score 2):

Just make a channel for your generic pages, and set the route to {slug}, that way your editors can create, delete, edit and disable any generic template pages without needing to touch the more involved areas of the Control Panel

Answer (score 1):

To let users create template without touching settings. On the top of my mind, you can try a ["matrix"](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/matrix-fields.html#settings) field with multiple "block type". And using "channel" section to replace "single" section.